# How do I disable SSLv3 support in Apache Tomcat?

Tags: ssl, tomcat, configuration, poodle

I am trying to reconfigure my Apache Tomcat server to only use TLSv1. However, it is still falling back to SSLv3 using certain browsers.

I setup the <connector> tag with the following settings:

```
<Connector ...
       enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
       acceptCount="100"  maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1" />
```

Am I missing a configuration setting or have somethign present that I shouldn't have present?

Comment: What is the problem with v3?  I thought that v1 had security issues.

Comment: @mdpc POODLE affects SSLv3.

Comment: Tomcat version ? JDK version ? In recent versions sslProtocol is TLS by default.

Comment: rmeisen: The answers will vary depending on your Tomcat and Java versions, and if you are using JSSE verses AJP. The differences are as subtle as `sslProtocols=TLSv1` verses `sslProtocol="TLS"` (Notice that `s`?). Specifying your Tomcat & Java versions will save you from insanity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on the version of Tomcat 5 and Version 6 the SSLEnabled="true" might not work as it was added mid-release. 
To get past this you just need to edit the following:
sslProtocols = TLS
To:
sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"

Seems strange but even though it says TLS, it contains the SSL 3.

This fixed it on our Tomcat 5.5.20 and our Tomcat 6 instances. 
-Greg

I believe what you need to do is:

Jboss:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
       acceptCount="100"  maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/keystore.jks"
       keystorePass="rmi+ssl"
       sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
```

Not sure on the cipher suite definition however sslprotocols should just be set to **TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2**

depending on your tomcat version it will differ, other potential solutions:

**Tomcat 5 and 6**

```
<Connector...
   enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
   acceptCount="100"  maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
   clientAuth="false" sslEnabledProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
```

**On RHEL5-based distros, the following applies to Tomcat 6 versions [prior to Tomcat 6.0.38](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1232233) **

Note that `TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` is supported by Java 7, not Java 6. Adding these directives to a server running Java 6 is harmless, but won't enable TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2.

```
<Connector...
   enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
   acceptCount="100"  maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
```

**Tomcat >=7**

```
<Connector...
       enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
       acceptCount="100"  maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
```

**Tomcat APR connectors**

```
<Connector...
               maxThreads="200"
               enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
               SSLEnabled="true" 
               SSLProtocol="TLSv1"
               SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.base}/conf/localhost.crt"
               SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.base}/conf/localhost.key" />
```

the above is altered to cater to what your connector specifications were above.
Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1232233

Comment: FYI, `sslEnabledProtocols` didn't work for us on Tomcat 6.  `sslProtocols = "TLSv1,...."` did.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar use case, which is to enable Tomcat 7 to strictly use only TLSv1.2, not to fall back to earlier SSL protocols such as TLSv1.1 or SSLv3.

I am using: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64-64bit and C:\Java64\jdk1.8.0_60.

Following this instruction: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html. Tomcat is relatively simple to setup SSL support.

From many references I tested many combination, finally I found 1 which will enforce Tomcat 7 to accept TLSv1.2 only. 2 places needed to touch:

1) In C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64-64bit\conf\server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" 
 protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
 maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
 keystoreFile="ssl/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
 clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSL" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" />
```

where

`keystoreFile` = local self-signed trust store

`org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol` = JSSE BIO implementation.

We don't use `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol`, because it is powered by openssl. The underlying openssl will fall back to support earlier SSL protocols.

2) When start up Tomcat, enable the following environment parameters.

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java64\jdk1.8.0_60
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Java64\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64-64bit
set JAVA_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2" -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=false -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2"
```

JAVA_OPTS restriction is required, otherwise Tomcat (which is powered by Java8) will fall back to support earlier SSL protocols.

Start up Tomcat `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64-64bit\bin\startup.bat`

We can see JAVA_OPTS appears in Tomcat startup log.

```
Oct 16, 2015 4:10:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
Oct 16, 2015 4:10:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=false
Oct 16, 2015 4:10:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Then, we can use openssl command to verify our setup. First connect localhost:8443 with TLSv1.1 protocol. Tomcat refuses to reply with Server certificate.

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -tls1_1
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(000001C0)
5372:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:.\ssl\s3_pkt.c:362:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 0 bytes
```

Connect localhost:8443 with TLSv1.2 protocol, Tomcat replies ServerHello with certificate:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -tls1_2
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(000001C0)
depth=1 C = US, ST = Washington, L = Seattle, O = getaCert - www.getacert.com
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=SG/ST=SG/L=Singapore/O=Xxxx/OU=Development/CN=Myself
   i:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=getaCert - www.getacert.com
1 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=getaCert - www.getacert.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=getaCert - www.getacert.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(ignored)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=SG/ST=SG/L=Singapore/O=Xxxx/OU=Development/CN=Myself
issuer=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=getaCert - www.getacert.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2367 bytes and written 443 bytes
```

This proves that Tomcat now strictly respond to TLSv1.2 request only.

Comment: Very nice and thorough answer! Kudos!

Comment: I've found that `JAVA_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2` is not necessary (Tomcat 8.0.29, Java 1.8.0_74).  It's not mentioned here either: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Security/POODLE

Comment: -Djdk.tls.client.protocols is relevant to Tomcat acting as a client to make requests from elsewhere ... it should only be relevant for that use case.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 7 documentation clearly states that the `sslEnabledProtocols` and `sslProtocol` options are suppported and that there is an overlap between them:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat 6.0.41, you will need to use the blocking connector since the NIO one is ignoring those settings.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Security/POODLE

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201410.mbox/%3C5440F1C6.3040205@apache.org%3E

Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" 
    SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
    keystoreFile="tomcat.jks" 
    keystorePass="changeit"
    sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat 5.5 you should use undocumented parameter

```
protocols="TLSv1"
```

to restrict use of excatly this protocol version.

Answer (score 0):

To disable SSL 3 (POODLE) in  Jboss 4.0.3 SP1 (Tomcat 5.5 with java 1.5) in server.xml change your code like this.

`<Connector port="443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
           maxThreads="100" strategy="ms" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           emptySessionPath="true"
           scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
           keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/eCP.keystore"
           keystorePass="password" 
           sslProtocol="TLS" 
           protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />`

Answer (score 0):

for newer Tomcats use **sslProtocols** and **sslEnabledProtocols** combo like this:

`<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
  maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
  enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
  acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
  clientAuth="false"
  sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
  sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
  SSLEnabled="true"
  URIEncoding="UTF-8" keystorePass=""/>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @iviorel says, it's not `sslProtocols`, it's `sslProtocol`. (Why did his answer get downscore?)

**JSSE**
For me, on Tomcat 7 and Java 7, `sslProtocol` in the following configuration doesn't work:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" 
keyAlias="keyalias" keystoreFile="keystore" keystorePass="changeit" 
maxThreads="150" port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
```

It says:

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
java.io.IOException: TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 SSLContext not available
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:465)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:398)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:646)
    ...
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 SSLContext not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSSLContext(JSSESocketFactory.java:478)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:439)
    ... 19 more
```

But the following works just fine:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" 
keyAlias="keyalias" keystoreFile="keystore" keystorePass="changeit" 
maxThreads="150" port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
scheme="https" secure="true" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
```

**APR**
To disable SSL v3, and enable TLSv1 protocol:

```
SSLProtocol="TLSv1"
```

To enable TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 protocols:

```
SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"
```

Or:

```
SSLProtocol="all"
```

Note: the "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" values require Tomcat Native 1.1.32 and a version of Tomcat that supports it.