# How to handle POODLE vulnerabilities on web service running on tomcat 6.0

Tags: ssl, tomcat6

I have a web service which is running on **Tomcat 6.0**, **Java 7**.
The Connector uses the **JSSE configuration**. Below is what the connector in the **server.xml** file looks like, with a few modifications:

```
<Connector port="a numeric port number" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
       maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
       enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
       acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" SSLEnabled="true" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"
       URIEncoding="UTF-8" keystorePass="aStringValue" 
       keystoreFile="c:\crt\aFile.jks" keyAlias="anAlias"
       keyStoreType="JKS" />
```

I' Having trouble with getting the **SSLProtocol** to work in a fashion that would disable the **POODLE** vulnerable **SSLv3**, I have also tried having it as "**TLS**" and separately have

```
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
```

as well as

```
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2+TLSv1.1+TLSv1"
```

after the **SSLProtocol**, but neither seem to have worked. And yes, I did remember to restart Tomcat after the server.xml changes.
Can anyone spot what I'm missing here? All help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/637666) at Serverfault, one or both of the following should do the trick:

```
sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

(note the lower case 'ssl')

```
sslEnabledProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, It might actually work but unfortunately I won't get a chance to try to restart the server I am using until this Friday, so I will have to wait until then to know weather this fixed it or not. I also read more about Tomcat 6.0 and noticed as stated on http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Security/POODLE "In old versions of Tomcat 6 the name of configuration attribute for Bio connector was protocols. It is sslEnabledProtocols since Tomcat 6.0.39 onwards." So i might have to try that as well. If this will fix the problem, I will accept the answer on Friday

Comment: sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" worked like a charm, I also added only the secure ciphers to the connection. Thanks for the help!