# Attempts to Disable SSLv3 in Tomcat Fail

Tags: ssl, tomcat7

I'm attempting to disable SSLv3 in Tomcat 7.0.68 but every attempt to test still results in `CONNECTED(00000003)
140680439531168:error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error:s23_clnt.c:770:`

I've updated server.xml with the following:

```
<Connector port="8444" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"  />
```

I then restart tomcat and use openssl to test:

```
 openssl s_client -connect hdlp10-tc02:8444
```

2 other tomcat instances on the same server with the same server.xml modification work as expected. The difference is a different port and context.

**UPDATE**

Started with fresh instance of tomcat, configured server.xml and started the daemon **without** the WAR deployed. Tested and SSLv3 was disabled all was well.

I then deployed the WAR file and retested. Tests failed SSLv3 was being issued as handshake.

Something in this WAR file is busting things up. It's a Spring application no embedded Tomcat (pre-Spring Boot).

What the hell would be causing this to occur?

Comment: Test with getting rid of that RC4 cipher SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA.

Comment: It's there a value for starttls?

Comment: @Schrute same error.

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin doesn't STARTTLS only apply to javamail?

Comment: Here is the answer http://serverfault.com/q/637649/346295

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin that is not an acceptable answer. Especially since I'm doing 1) exactly as that answer suggests and 2) 2 other tomcat instances on that same server work without issue.